# Android FileProvider.getUriForFile throws null object exception

Tags: cordova, android-camera, android-fileprovider

I am in the process of extending my Cordova plugin for Android to use the camera.  After extensive reading of the various Android developer articles on the subject as well as threads on this forum I have done the following

**In my plugin config.xml file**

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
 android:authorities="com.example.app.camera" android:exported="false" 
 android:grantUriPermissions="true">
 <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
  android:resource="@xml/reviewpics"/>
 </provider>
```

along with

```
<resource-file src="src/android/xml/reviewpics.xml" 
  target="res/xml/reviewpics.xml" />
```

For good measure I opened the compiled APK as a zip archive and checked that res/xml/reviewpics.xml does indeed exist.

**reviewpics.xml**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <files-path name="camera" path="."/>
</paths>
```

to share the root internal storage location of the app as `camera`.

**In the app** itself I do the following

```
File photo = new File(...);
 Uri uri = 
FileProvider.getUriForFile(cordova.getActivity(),
"com.example.app.camera",photo);
```

However, when I compile, install and run this I consistently get the message

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Clearly, I am doing something wrong though I feel I have followed the various examples and tutorials on the matter to the letter.  Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving this question here and providing an answer for the benefit of anyone else who runs into similar issues.  The key point to remember here is the context - **a Cordova plugin**.  The [Cordova documentation on plugin.xml](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#config-file) is at best sketchy and leaves out a lot of detail.  However, it should be borne in mind that it is necessary to tell Cordova just which Android project configuration files to use to place any instructions that you might supply via `plugin.xml`.  I had omitted to do so with the result that my

```
<provider>...
```

block was simply not making it into any configuration file.  Once I had wrapped `<provider>...` in a

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="application">
...
</config-file>
```

block everything worked just as expected!